# When method chaining, how can you determine which return value will be returned?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering if a class or any variable is chained to one or more methods? Which return value would it give? (`Class.method1.method2` --> what is the return value?)

Given the following code below:

```
restaurants = []
restaurants << Restaurant.new.import_line(line.chomp)

def import_line(line)
 return self
end
```

In this case, both methods (`new` and `import_line(line)` return the instance, so I know the instance gets put into the array. I am curious though if `import_line(line)`, returned something like `true`

```
def import_line(line)
   return true
end
```

What would be the return value on `Restaurant.new.import_line(line.chomp)`. Would it be set to `true` or return the instance (`.new` returns instance)?

In essence, when `Class.method1.method2` or `Variable.method1.method2` exists, which method has priority in determining the return value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value is *always* the last thing in the chain, no exceptions. The result is not necessarily the thing you'd expect, though, as the last thing in the chain might do some tricky stuff.

For example, just to be clear:

```
Restaurant.new.import_line do |line|
  line + '!'
end
```

There's no obligation here for `import_line` to return the result of that block, and it's often the case that it won't.

You can also have occasions where the thing you're chaining switches completely and catches you off guard so you have to be sure about the return values from each function in the chain you're calling.

Example here:

```
"help!".gsub!(/!/, '?').length
# => 5

"help?".gsub!(/!/, '?').length
#! NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
```

In this case `gsub!` returns the string if and only if a change was made, otherwise `nil`, which means you can't chain it in that case.

Comment: Good answer by @tadman. To go a bit further, when you do `object.method1.method2.method3`, the result of `object.method1` becomes the object on which `method2` is called, the result of which becomes the object on which `method3` is called, the result of which is returned to the original caller.